# Using a custom editor template for list property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've almost got it working, but I am missing a **tiny** bit of knowledge to make this work, it is a quick fix I know it.

I am putting two ViewModels into a single view:

```
public class MajorViewModel
{
    public ICollection<Major> Majors { get; set; }
}
public class MinorViewModel
{
    public ICollection<Minor> Minors { get; set; }
}
```

Into a view like so:

```
<snip>
@Html.Partial("_MajorPartial")
@Html.Partial("_MinorPartial")
<snip>
```

Whose views look like:

```
// _MajorPartial
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model ClassPlannerMVC.ViewModels.MajorViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     //@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Majors) ?? I'm not able to use this here
}

// _MinorPartial
looks the same except "Major" is changed to "Minor"
```

And then I have two views in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Major.cshtml and Minor.cshtml

```
// Major.csthml
@model ClassPlannerMVC.Models.Major

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

// Minor.cshtml
looks the same except "Major" is changed to "Minor"
```

My two models are:

```
public class Major
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserHasMajor> UserHasMajors { get; set; }
}

public class Minor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserHasMinor> UserHasMinors { get; set; }
}
```

---

Currently the view doesn't show my view models (MajorViewModel, MinorViewModel), which will display editors for Major and Minor respectively. I know I might be passing something wrong into the _MajorPartial and _MinorPartial views, and that is why I cannot add a @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Majors) which will display my custom editor template. There is something very minor missing in my code, do you spot the error I am having?

I'll upload more code if it is necessary.

Comment: MajorViewModel returns collection so how can you get a value without foreach or index (object[index].name) etc.

Comment: I read on SO that you could do this to iterate through the collection: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Majors), but this hasn't worked

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor()` will do this for you but you don't appear to be passing anything to your `@Partial()` methods (i.e.the model is null)

Comment: No, it cannot, just thing how can you get the property value from a list of object without iterating it or without using the index.

Comment: @AliAdravi, The `@EditorFor() method will do this. Internally it checks if the object is `IEnumerable` and calls the respective template helper to render each item in the collection

Comment: I need to pass a viewmodel into the partial view, but will this simply do? @Html.Partial("_MajorPartial", new MajorViewModel())

Comment: Well yes, but you need to initialize `Majors` otherwise that will be null, and then it would be empty unless you populate it in the constrctor so there is nothing to display. You really need another view model that combines both view models, pass that to the main view, then pass the respective models to the partial

Comment: @StephenMuecke If you'd like to get the accepted answer, would you like to make these suggestions in a answer? You're suggesting I add these two view models together, pass it into the controller action (populating the fields I need) and then this will all work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be passing anything to your @Partial() methods (i.e.the model is null). I suggest that you create another view model to hold both and pass that the the main view, something like

```
public class CombinedViewModel
{
  public MajorViewModel MajorVM { get; set; }
  public MinorViewModel MinorVM { get; set; }
}
```

In you [HttpGet] method, populate the view model and pass to the main view

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
  CombinedViewModel model = new CombinedViewModel();
  // set properties
  model.MajorVM = new MajorVM();
  model.MajorVM.Majors = // assign your collection
  ..
  return View(model);
}
```

Then in the main view

```
@model YourAssembly.CombinedViewModel
...
@Html.Partial("_MajorPartial", Model.MajorVM)
@Html.Partial("_MinorPartial", Model.MinorVM)
```

Aternatively, just have one view model with properties `public ICollection<Major> Majors { get; set; }` and `public ICollection<Minor> Minors { get; set; }` (not sure if you had omitted some other properties for brevity and therefore you needed to have separate view models)